# What resources do angular modules share

Tags: angularjs

I would like to have more theoretical understanding how angular modules work.

When I would create one module 'clientApp' and I 'register' controller, services, factories, scope etc..., inject other services, factories, scope into the controllers. What objects are known to the 'clientApp' module?

Comment: All the ones you registered. That's the point of registering them. I'm not sure I understand the question. Please come up with an example and a more precise question, with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Angular Modules**

An efficient, production-ready controllers by encapsulating our functionality in a single core unit called a **module**.

In Angular, a module is the main way to define an `AngularJS` app. The module of an app is where
we’ll contain all of our application code. An app can contain several modules, each one containing
code that pertains to specific functionality.
Using modules gives us a lot of advantages, such as:

• Keeping our global namespace clean
• Making tests easier to write and keeping them clean so as to more easily target isolated
functionality
• Making it easy to share code between applications
• Allowing our app to load different parts of the code in any order

The Angular module API allows us to declare a module using the angular.module() API method.
When declaring a module, we need to pass two parameters to the method. The first is the name of
the module we are creating. The second is the list of dependencies, otherwise known as injectables.

```
angular.module('myApp', []);
```

When writing large applications, we’ll create several different modules to contain our logic. Creating a module for each piece of functionality gives us the advantage of isolation in which to write and test large features.

### **Properties**

Angular modules have properties that we can use to inspect the module.

### **name (string)**

The name property on the modules gives us the name of the module as a string.

### **requires (array of strings)**

The requires property contains a list of modules (as strings) that the injector loads before the
module itself is loaded.

Better Read 
**ng-book - 
The Complete Book on AngularJS
Ari Lerner**

[image]

Download **[ng-book](http://www.4shared-china.com/office/Efxv69lDba/ng-book.htm)**